# Map X: via sshfs command from Windows 10 BASH command line

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sshfs

I am interested in having a remote user mapping a drive to a remote sshfs server from a [BASH running on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-bash-shell-command-line-windows-10).

```
sshfs username@server:/home/UsersHomeFolderAtServer X:
```

or

```
sshfs username@server:/home/UsersHomeFolderAtServer C:\RemoteServer
```

## Is it  possible to sshfs remote mount from the Win-10 BASH to a drive (preferable) or subdirectory?

Please state in your reply if you have had success. Any reference to configuration procedure would be appreciated. The remote user can not install applications, such as Krusader, on the corporate PC.  Thank you

The end goal is to enable the user to see the remote server from his File Explorer.  Similar to the example here (Nautilus Ubuntu):

[image]

Comment: Do this on a LAN?

Comment: This is to be performed across a WAN: user is 3000 miles away in California